# FitSharp is not able to find .DLLs in other folders

Tags: c#, .net, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fitsharp

I'm getting System.IO.FileNotFoundException trying to test my application. My Folder hierarchy is as follow:

- I have my fitSharp folder with the Runner.exe and the .dll's
- The system under test is in my debug folder
- i have a reference to this .dll with: **!path ........\Debug\XXXXX.dll**

So the problem is, as I'm using Dependecy Injection fitSharp is not able to find the required .dll for unity. I'm getting FileNotFound Exception all the time.

The thing is if i copy all the files (.dll) to my fitSharp folder where the Runner.exe is, the test is working fine.

The problem is, fitsharp is not able to find files in a different folder and i have no idea how to provide this path to fitSharp.

I tried already to use a configuration.xml file to declare all the needed DLLs but still no.

```
__ EXCEPTION __:System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> XXXException: Verbindung fehlgeschlagen. DatabaseException (0x80004005): Failed to execute non query ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for unity: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration' or one of its dependencies. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. at System.Configuration.TypeUtil.GetTypeWithReflectionPermission(IInternalConfigHost host, String typeString, Boolean throwOnError) at System.Configuration.MgmtConfigurationRecord.CreateSectionFactory(FactoryRecord factoryRecord) at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.FindAndEnsureFactoryRecord(String configKey, Boolean& isRootDeclaredHere) at fitSharp.Machine.Model.TypedValue.ThrowExceptionIfNotValid() at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.InvokeInstructionBase.InvokeMember(Tree1 parameters, Int32 memberIndex)
at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.ExecuteCall.ExecuteOperation(Tree1 parameters) at fitSharp.Slim.Operators.InvokeInstructionBase.Invoke(TypedValue instance, MemberName memberName, Tree`1 parameters)
```

Comment: Please post the full text of the exception.

Comment: See the full Exception above. Thank you!

Comment: Delete the reference and install the fitSharp NuGet package, then everything will work correctly.

Comment: Thank you, i installed the NuGet package. After building my project, only the DLLs were copied to my Debug folder => so i have the same problem as before. Is there a way to get the runner.exe in my debug folder or does that makes no sense? Or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try explicitly loading the missing DLL:

```
!path pathToDll\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll
```

or try this entry in the suite configuration file:

```
<suiteConfig>
    <System.AppDomainSetup>
        <ApplicationBase>pathToSUT</ApplicationBase>
        ...
```